# Specific way binding data with knockout js

Tags: knockout.js, data-binding

i am new in knockoutjs and trying to learning it and reading code sample from many various web site. i got a piece of code for table data binding with knockoutjs but i do not understand the binding code properly. so here i will post the code. so someone if possible help me to understand the code.

### here is full code

```
<script type="text/html" id="person">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="text: $root.name"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: $parent.name"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: $data.name"></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- ko template: { name: 'person', foreach: children } --><!-- /ko -->
</script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>$root</th>
    <th>$parent</th>
    <th>$data</th>
  </tr>
  <!-- ko template: { name: 'person', data: mainPerson } --><!-- /ko -->
</table>

th, td { padding: 10px; border: 1px solid gray; }

var Person = function(name) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable(name);
  self.children = ko.observableArray([]);
}

var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.name = 'root view model';
  self.mainPerson = ko.observable();
}

var vm = new ViewModel(),
    grandpa = new Person('grandpa'),
    daddy = new Person('daddy'),
    son1 = new Person('marc'),
    son2 = new Person('john');

vm.mainPerson(grandpa);
grandpa.children.push(daddy);
daddy.children.push(son1);
daddy.children.push(son2);

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

### the below binding code is not clear to me

```
<script type="text/html" id="person">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="text: $root.name"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: $parent.name"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: $data.name"></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- ko template: { name: 'person', foreach: children } --><!-- /ko -->
</script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>$root</th>
    <th>$parent</th>
    <th>$data</th>
  </tr>
  <!-- ko template: { name: 'person', data: mainPerson } --><!-- /ko -->
</table>
```

guide me to understand above binding.

what is this  `<!-- ko template: { name: 'person', foreach: children } --><!-- /ko -->`

jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/03tx96dm/

thanks

Comment: You just read the documentation about the template binding: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html and the containerless control flow syntax http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-4-using-foreach-without-a-container-element

Comment: @nemesv Can you tell me why people generate UI with template binding when we can generate table with knockoutjs foreach binding. any reason is there when people go for  template binding ?

Comment: Basically the template binding in the "foreach mode" is doing the same as the foreach bidning. However in the case of the foreach binding your item "template" is inline inside directly inside the HTML where you have the binding. If the case of the template binding your template can be a central place, can be loaded lazily, etc. So if you want to reuse a template you need to use the template binding with the foreach option.

Comment: Named templates are a bit flaky, inline templates are 100% reliable.

Comment: @PeterWone u said **Named templates are a bit flaky** but u did not explain why.....if possible give a link which will explain the same in detail. thanks

Comment: The "flaky" comment was based on info I found while troubleshooting named templates that didn't work. Can't find it now, which is annoying, but I seem to recall it had to do with differences between browsers. Some interesting data I found while trying to support flakiness: http://jsperf.com/named-vs-inline-templates-in-knockout-js/7

Answer (score 0):

the `name: 'person'` segment of the attribute is telling knockout which template to use to display and bind your data. In knockout, a template is defined with a `<script>` element of type `text/html`. The template is referenced by its `id` attribute. In this case `person`.

the `foreach` part is basically telling knockout to apply this template to each element in the collection `children` (or to the single object `mainPerson` in the second usage).

Essentially this example is using a template that references itself. This would allow you to continually nest elements arbitrarily deep and knockout would keep track of everything with minimal code on your part.